# Arabic content in Adobe Live Cycle Designer Forms

Tags: adobe, livecycle-designer

We like to pass Arabic text to a text field for a form designed using Adobe Live Cycle Designer. We followed the steps in below link
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=000422.html

But still we end up in negative side. Any additional thing that we need to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we need Adobe ME(Middle East) version to deal with Arabic in pdf.